# Android - how to find multiple views with common attribute

Tags: android, view

I have a layout with multiple `ImageView`s, some of those images need to have the same onClickListener.
I would like my code to be flexible and to be able to get a collection of those `View`s, iterate and add the listeners at run-time.

Is there a method like `findViewById` that will return a collection of `View`s rather than just a single one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find all views with tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062264/find-all-views-with-tag)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I've finally wrote this method (**Updated** thanks to @SuitUp (corrected username)):

```
private static ArrayList<View> getViewsByTag(ViewGroup root, String tag){
    ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();
    final int childCount = root.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        final View child = root.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            views.addAll(getViewsByTag((ViewGroup) child, tag));
        } 

        final Object tagObj = child.getTag();
        if (tagObj != null && tagObj.equals(tag)) {
            views.add(child);
        }

    }
    return views;
}
```

It will return all views that have `android:tag="TAG_NAME"` attribute. Enjoy ;)

Comment: It does not collect ViewGroup Views.

Comment: You can use Objects.equal(tagObj, tag) for cleaner code and also allowing querying for views with no tags.  
Also you can make the method more general by letting the tag parameter be an object, since the tags may not be Strings.  
(And returning a List<View> or Collection<View> would be better practice).

Comment: Pretty awesome, +1. I created a variation of this that returns the root view as well, if it has the tag. https://gist.github.com/orip/5566666

Comment: Why do you use final on each variable? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279420/does-use-of-final-keyword-in-java-improve-the-performance

Answer (score 19):

Shlomi Schwartz's method has one flaw, it does not collect `Views` wchich are `ViewGroups`. Here is my fix:

```
private static ArrayList<View> getViewsByTag(ViewGroup root, String tag){
    ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();
    final int childCount = root.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        final View child = root.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            views.addAll(getViewsByTag((ViewGroup) child, tag));
        } 

        final Object tagObj = child.getTag();
        if (tagObj != null && tagObj.equals(tag)) {
            views.add(child);
        }

    }
    return views;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no such method as findViewById that returns a group of views, but you can iterate over your views and set them an onClickListener like this:

```
for (int i = 0;i < layout.getChildCount();i++) {
  View child = layout.getChildAt(i);
  //you can check for view tag or something to see if it satisfies your criteria
  //child.setOnClickListener...
}
```

**UPD:**
For recursive view hierarchy (this is example from a real project, where we do view refresh recursively, but instead you could just do whatever you want with the nested views):

```
private void recursiveViewRefresh(ViewGroup view) {
    for (int i = 0;i < view.getChildCount();i++) {
        View child = view.getChildAt(i);
        try {
            ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) child;
            recursiveViewRefresh(viewGroup);
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            //just ignore the exception - it is used as a check
        }
        singleViewRefresh(child);
    }
}
```

Comment: I will go with that, although it is strange that there is no native method.

Comment: What if the child is another layout? is it a recursion?

Comment: yes you can do it recursively like this: (I will add it into the answer)

Comment: Thanks already implemented, I will post my code once Stack' will let me answer

Comment: Check out the method I've added, I think it is a "good to have" util. Thanks again for your help ;)

Answer (score 3):

This method provides a general way of obtaining views that match a given criteria. To use simply implement a `ViewMatcher` interface

```
private static List<View> getMatchingViews(ViewGroup root, ViewMatcher viewMatcher){
    List<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();
    final int childCount = root.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        final View child = root.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            views.addAll(getMatchingViews((ViewGroup) child, viewMatcher));
        }

        if(viewMatcher.matches(child)){
            views.add(child);
        }
    }
    return views;
}

public interface ViewMatcher{
    public boolean matches(View v);
}

// Example1: matches views with the given tag
public class TagMatcher implements ViewMatcher {

    private String tag;

    public TagMatcher(String tag){
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    public boolean matches(View v){
        String tag = v.getTag();
        return this.tag.equals(tag);
    }

}


// Example2: matches views that have visibility GONE
public class GoneMatcher implements ViewMatcher {

    public boolean matches(View v){
        v.getVisibility() == View.GONE  
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I will share my functional-style method with a filter, can be used with StreamSupport library.

```
@NonNull
public static <T> Function<View, Stream<T>> subViews(
    @NonNull final Function<View, Optional<T>> filter
) {
    return view -> RefStreams.concat(
        // If current view comply target condition adds it to the result (ViewGroup too)
        filter.apply(view).map(RefStreams::of).orElse(RefStreams.empty()),

        // Process children if current view is a ViewGroup
        ofNullable(view).filter(__ -> __ instanceof ViewGroup).map(__ -> (ViewGroup) __)
                .map(viewGroup -> IntStreams.range(0, viewGroup.getChildCount())
                        .mapToObj(viewGroup::getChildAt)
                        .flatMap(subViews(filter)))
                .orElse(RefStreams.empty()));
}

@NonNull
public static <T> Function<View, Optional<T>> hasType(@NonNull final Class<T> type) {
    return view -> Optional.ofNullable(view).filter(type::isInstance).map(type::cast);
}

@NonNull
public static Function<View, Optional<View>> hasTag(@NonNull final String tag) {
    return view -> Optional.ofNullable(view).filter(v -> Objects.equals(v.getTag(), tag));
}
```

Usage example:

```
Optional.ofNullable(navigationViewWithSubViews)
            .map(subViews(hasType(NavigationView.class)))
            .orElse(RefStreams.empty())
            .forEach(__ -> __.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a modification of Shlomi Schwartz's answer above. All credit to them. I didn't like how the recursion looked, and needed to be able to regex match a string tag name.

```
  /**
   * Find all views with (string) tags matching the given pattern.
   *
   */
  protected static Collection<View> findViewsByTag(View root, String tagPattern) {
    List<View> views = new ArrayList<>();

    final Object tagObj = root.getTag();
    if (tagObj instanceof String) {
      String tagString = (String) tagObj;
      if (tagString.matches(tagPattern)) {
        views.add(root);
      }
    }

    if (root instanceof ViewGroup) {
      ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) root;
      for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
        views.addAll(findViewsByTag(vg.getChildAt(i), tagPattern));
      }
    }

    return views;
  }
```

For example:

```
Collection<View> itemNameViews = findViewsByTag(v, "^item_name_[0-9]+$");
```

Answer (score 1):

In kotlin we can do it is a very simplistic way as following (Kotlin Extension Function):

```
fun ViewGroup.findViewsByTag(tag: String): ArrayList<View> = ArrayList<View>().also {
    this.children.forEach { child ->
        if (child is ViewGroup) it.addAll(child.findViewsByTag(tag))
        if (child.tag == tag) it.add(child)
    }
}
```

Now, you can use it on any viewGroup. For example:

```
mViewGroup.findViewsByTag("my tag")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onClick(View view){
switch(view.getId()){

case R.id.whatEverImageViewId :
//....
break ;

case R.id.whatEverImageViewId 2 :
//....
break ;
....
```

and you can use for loop to add listeners

Answer (score 0):

You can use `switch()` for multiple widgets.

```
switch(viewobject.getId()) {    
 case R.id.imageview1:    
   /* ... */    
   break;    
 case R.id.imageview2:    
   /* ... */      
   break;    
}
```