# How can espresso get a view that satisfies a list of `ViewMatchers`

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing, e2e-testing

I read Espresso's [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/basics) with method `onView()` which works on a single view.

Does someone know how can I:

1. Get all views that satisfy a `ViewMatcher`
2. Get a view that satisfies a list of `ViewMatchers`

For example, I want to know how many items are in a `recyclerView`!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Get a view that satisfies a list of ViewMatchers

This can be done with the Hamcrest matcher `allOf`

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.allOf;

onView(allOf(withId(R.id.exampleView), 
             withEffectiveVisibility(ViewMatchers.Visibility.VISIBLE)))
        .check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed()))
        .check(matches(withHint(R.string.exampleViewHint)));
```

> Get all views that satisfy a ViewMatcher

Well, maybe this is a start in the right direction: Below is an example of how to find all Android views tagged with a given value.

From: https://gist.github.com/orip/5566666 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/8831593/37020

```
package com.onavo.android.common.ui;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/8831593/37020 by by Shlomi Schwartz
 * License: MIT
 */
public class ViewGroupUtils {
    public static List<View> getViewsByTag(View root, String tag) {
        List<View> result = new LinkedList<View>();

        if (root instanceof ViewGroup) {
            final int childCount = ((ViewGroup) root).getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                result.addAll(getViewsByTag(((ViewGroup) root).getChildAt(i), tag));
            }
        }

        final Object rootTag = root.getTag();
        // handle null tags, code from Guava's Objects.equal
        if (tag == rootTag || (tag != null && tag.equals(rootTag))) {
            result.add(root);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```