# Non static method getTag referenced from static context

Tags: reference, static

I gave my ImageView with android:Tag="1" but when I try to find this view with 
ImageView.getTag(1);
it shows the error:
Non static method "getTag(1) cannot be referenced from a static context.

What can I do?
How can I make a non-static Tag?

Comment: What's your actual code? What language? What framework? Your problem is self-describing (you are calling a static method from a non-statc method) but that doesn't tell us how to solve it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert sry, its Android Studio - Java

Comment: The method must be defined as static, obviously. Or you must call it from a non-static context, i.e. `ImageView view = new ImageView(); ... view.getTag(1)`

Answer (score 0):

`ImageView` is a class.  If you create an instance of `ImageView`, say using

`ImageView myImageView = new ImageView();`

then you can then refer to `getTag()` non-statically using `myImageView.getTag()`.

If you insist on using `ImageView.getTag()` then `getTag()` and `tag` should both be declared to be static.  This would mean that there is only ever one value of `tag`, at any one time, for all `ImageView` instances.

That's just basic java.

In Android there is already a `getTag()`, though not in `ImageView` but in `View`.  `ImageView` inherits from `View` so you get it there anyway.

`ImageView` is documented here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html

`View` is documented here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

`android:Tag` is an XML attribute for `View` and is documented here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:tag

As I mentioned `getTag()` exists on `View` not `ImageView` but since `ImageView` inherits from `View` all instances of `ImageView` will have it.

You can see the `getTag()` source code here:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/view/View.java#View.getTag%28%29

And that conclusively shows that `getTag()` is in fact not `static` so should be referenced through instances and not literally as `View.getTag()`.

Documenters sometimes tell you to refer to non-static methods in what is actually a static way.  They assume you know not to take them literally and they aren't always right.  In their defence they have no idea what you name your instances so they don't know what else to call it.

`yourView.getTag()` would be more correct but after a while becomes annoying to look at.

You did say you were trying to "find this view".  Until you have a reference to the view you're after `getTag()` won't help you.  You already know your tag is `1`.  You don't need to be told that again.  You need to find your way to the view that has tag `1`.

In that case look here:

[Find all views with tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062264/find-all-views-with-tag)