# make check box selected when other check box is clicked

Tags: java, android, object, checkbox, attributes

i m trying to set the attribute of one check box to selected after i click the first check box

```
CheckBox check = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
```

assume there is three check boxes,

```
[] 1
[] 2
[] 3
```

if i tick check box 1 the second check box will also be marked as checked.

```
[✔] 1
[✔] 2
[] 3
```

the thing is they have the same name and i was wondering if it is possible. i would gladly appreciate any comments and answers.

Comment: if (check1.isChecked()) {
                 check2.setChecked(true);
             }

Comment: can't do that, all three checkboxes have the same name

Comment: all three checkbox have same name din't get you?

Comment: actually that not how i declared my checkboxes, if it is relevant to post my real code i can edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must not have the same name for the three checkbox. So, in this case, you can do the following thing :

```
CheckBox check1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
CheckBox check2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
CheckBox check3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
check1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            check2.setChecked(true);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: is it possible to use the objects ID or TAG to make it selected? if it is how can i do that... btw, thanks for answering..

Comment: From the docs : "Any View object may have an integer ID associated with it, to uniquely identify the View within the tree." (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html). For the tags, you can try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062264/find-all-views-with-tag