# Cannot Programmatically Set EditText ID

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am creating a dynamic number of editTexts and want to eventually pull the ID for each to call .getText() on the editText.

However, I noticed that it is difficult to programmatically set the ID, so I am using the .setTag() method instead:

```
private void createAnswerChoice(int answerNumber) {
    ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.create_poll_questions_answer_layout);
    EditText editText = new EditText(getActivity());
    editText.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.answer_text) + " " + answerNumber);
    editText.setSingleLine(true);
    editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
    String editTextID = ((getResources().getString(R.string.created_answer_editText_id))+String.valueOf(answerNumber));
    editText.setTag(editTextID);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), editTextID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    editText.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    TextInputLayout newAnswer = new TextInputLayout(getActivity());
    newAnswer.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    newAnswer.addView(editText, layoutParams);
    layout.addView(newAnswer);
}
```

How would I get the value of each editText if I know the tag and not the ID? Also, what is the purpose of the .setTag() method (how does it relate to .setID()?)

Comment: What is the issue with setting the ID?

Comment: If you  are using android, then it is advisable to use xml instead of programmatically creating views. It is lot easier to make changes and gives a cleaner code

Comment: I am creating dynamic views based on a number that the user selects, therefore static XML (as far as I know) would not be adequate

Answer (score 2):

create resource file(id.xml) in  res/values/id.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
   <item
    type="id"
    name="edittext_hello" />
  </resources>
```

and then set,

```
 editText.setId(R.id.edittext_hello);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend using tags to get views from your hierarchy but if you must this SO post describes how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16262479/6526330.

Tags should be used when you need to cache some data in a view to grab out later when you have the view again (yes I know very generic). Some examples would be if you are using a holder in a list view or if you have a lot of views on a screen and want a global click listener vs listeners for each view. I stole both of these examples from [the answers on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291726/what-is-the-main-purpose-of-settag-gettag-methods-of-view) which do a hell of a better job at describing the use cases than I can.

Answer (score 0):

`findViewById()` and `findViewWithTag()` are methods intended to obtain a reference to a `View` that was inflated from XML.

If you are creating the `View`s, you have them already then there's no need to use those methods. Keep the reference to the `View` somewhere.