# Fragment with multiple buttons - all with the same ID - how to hide them all?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a fragment, and inside that I inflate another layout file.  This means there are multiple buttons on the page with the same ID:

```
<Button android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:id="@+id/delete_seed" tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        android:textSize="10sp" android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"/>
```

So when I call:

```
Button deletebutton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.delete_seed);
deletebutton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

It only removes the first one.  How can I target all the buttons?

Comment: change the id's and use varags method to send multiple id's.

Comment: all with the same id ... why have id's if you don't make them unique/usable?

Comment: @Stultuske Okay I see that but how can I do it differently?

Answer (score 0):

You have included a layout inside a fragment. To target that button you need to find the button id with respect to the included layout and not the rootView.

```
View includedLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.include_id);
Button deletebutton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.delete_seed);
deletebutton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

//Find included button
Button includedDeleteButton = includedLayout.findViewById(R.id.delete_seed);
includedDeleteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Okay, but how can I loop through all views on the page?

Comment: You will need to loop through included layout and the root layout. Use the ViewGroup from both rootView and includedLayout to get list of all views from the layout.
`ViewGroup vg = rootView.getParent();`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `tag` instead of `id` and loop through everything like explained here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/16262479/1243048

Answer (score 0):

Work around : It is not a good practice to do it using id. Better to use tag. But as a work around use the below code

```
private void hideViews(int id, ViewGroup view) {
    for (int i = 0; i < view.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = view.getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceof Button && v.getId() == id) {
           v.setVisibility(View.GONE)
        } else if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            this.loopViews((ViewGroup) v);
        }
    }
}
```