# How to group a bunch of views and change their visibility together

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an activity which contains 2 group of views, which **CAN'T be located into same LAYOUT group but belong to same LOGIC group**, meaning that they should be shown or hidden and bind click event at same time. The thing is that I feel really awful to write something like this:

```
fun hide() {
    view1.visibility = View.GONE
    view2.visibility = View.GONE
    view3.visibility = View.GONE
    // ...
    view9.visibility = View.GONE
}


fun show() {
    view1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    view2.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    view3.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    // ...
    view9.visibility = View.VISIBLE

    view1.setOnClickListener{ run() }
    view2.setOnClickListener{ run() }
    view3.setOnClickListener{ run() }
    // ...
    view9.setOnClickListener{ run() }
}
```

I did read a post which describes a **kotlin skill** to simplify this mess by somehow grouping those views then just handle the groups, but unfortunately I can no longer find that post..

Help would be appreciated!

========= Update 2019-07-31 =========

I found the solution but forgot to update this question, the 'grouping' I was looking for, is in fact not a Kotlin specific feature but simply using ***vararg***, and we can use Kotlin extension (which is AWESOME) to simplify a bit more:

```
// assume we have a base activity or fragment, then put below functions in there
fun View.show() {
    visibility = View.VISIBLE
}

fun show(vararg views: View) {
    views.forEach { it.show() }
}

fun View.hide() {
    visibility = View.GONE
}

fun hide(vararg views: View) {
    views.forEach { it.hide() }
}

// then in any activity or fragment
show(v1, v2, v3, v4)
v9.hide()
```

============= updated 2020-03-07 ================

This is exactly *androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group* designed to do, which can logically group a bunch of views from anywhere and control their visibility by only changing group's visibility.

Comment: add them in one single layout like linear layout...

Comment: @AmitJangid I wish it would be that simple but those views belong to same logic group can't be simply added into one layout group..they are all mixed up together..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create extension functions.

For example:

```
fun View.showGroupViews(vararg view: View) {
    view.forEach {
        it.show()
    }
}

fun View.hideGroupViews(vararg view: View) {
    view.forEach {
        it.hide()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the one which is closest to what I was looking for and currently using, I have updated the solution I am using in my question post. Cheers.

Answer (score 16):

Since [`ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Group) 1.1 you can use Group instead of `LayoutGroup`.
You can simply add this code to you XML layout

```
<android.support.constraint.Group
    android:id="@+id/profile"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="profile_name,profile_image" />
```

And then you can call it from code to achieve behavior, that you need

```
profile.visibility = GONE
profile.visibility = VISIBLE
```

For more details read this article https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/introducing-constraint-layout-1-1-d07fc02406bc

Comment: If you are using androidx, use `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group` instead

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how is your layout structured you might want to group those views in a `ViewGroup` like `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, `FrameLayout` or `ConstraintLayout`.

Then you can change visibility just on the `ViewGroup` and all of its children will change it too.

Edit:

Without `ViewGroup` the only solution to eliminating this boilerplate is to enable databinding in your project and set it like this:

In your Activity/Fragment:

```
val groupVisible = ObservableBoolean()

fun changeVisibility(show: Boolean) {
    groupVisible.set(show)
}
```

In your xml:

```
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable name="groupVisible" type="Boolean"/>
    </data>
    <View
        android:visibility="@{groupVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"/>
</layout>
```

Comment: sorry mate, I wasn't making myself clear, the question is now updated, those views belong to same logic group can't be located into same layout group.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create an array:

```
val views = arrayOf(view1, view2, view3, view4, view5, view6, view7, view8, view9)
```

then:

```
fun show() {
    views.forEach {
        it.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        it.setOnClickListener{  }
    }
}

fun hide() {
    views.forEach { it.visibility = View.INVISIBLE }
}
```

Or without an array if the names of the views are surely like view1, view2, ...

```
for (i in 1..9) {
    val id = resources.getIdentifier("view$i", "id", context.getPackageName())
    val view = findViewById<View>(id)
    view.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    view.setOnClickListener{  }
}
```

Comment: This can do it for sure, thanks! however it is not what I saw in that post, which is something .. err. let's say kotlin-kind-of-magic..

Comment: why would you want to create unnecessary loops when you can do it via Groups

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function with three parameters and use `vararg` like following code:

```
fun changeVisiblityAndAddClickListeners(visibility: Int,
                                        listener: View.OnClickListener,
                                        vararg views: View) {
    for (view: View in views) {
        view.visibility = visibility
        if (visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
            view.setOnClickListener(listener)
        }
    }
}
```

Of course if you have too many views, this is not a effective solution. I just added this code snippet for an alternative way especially for problems with dynamic view set.

Answer (score 1):

Create a list of views and loop on it

```
val views = listOf<View>(view1, view2, ...)
views.forEach {
    it.visibility = View.GONE
}
```

You can also create [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) of `Iterable<View>` to simplify any kind of action on listed views

```
fun Iterable<View>.visibility(visibility: Int) = this.forEach {
    it.visibility = visibility
}
//usage
views.visibility(View.GONE)
```

Maybe you want to locate all views from tags in XML. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16262479/4681367)

Answer (score 0):

**If your views are not inside a view group** you can use an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions). You could create one to toggle the visibility of the views:

```
fun View.toggleVisibility() {
    if (visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
        visibility = View.GONE
    } else {
        visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
view.toggleVisibility()
```

Comment: thanks those views indeed are not under same layout group, but with your suggestion I still need to write dozen lines of xxxx.toggleVisibility() which is exactly what I would like to avoid..

Answer (score 0):

First in your xml layout, group your views by `android:tag="group_1"` attribute.

Then inside your activity use a `for` loop to implement whatever logic you need:

```
val root: ViewGroup = TODO("find your root layout")
for (i in 0 until root.childCount) {
    val v = root.getChildAt(i)
    when (v.tag) {
        "group_1" -> {
            TODO()
        }
        "group_2" -> {
            TODO()
        }
        else -> {
            TODO()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `LinearLayout` or any other `ViewGroup` containing your child `Views` and give it an ID in the XML file, then in your `Activity` or `Fragment` class define these functions:

```
    fun disableViewGroup(viewGroup: ViewGroup) {
        viewGroup.children.iterator().forEach {
            it.isEnabled = false
        }
    }

    fun enableViewGroup(viewGroup: ViewGroup) {
        viewGroup.children.iterator().forEach {
            it.isEnabled = true
        }
    }
```

And then in `onCreate()` or `onStart()` call it as following:

```
disableViewGroup(idOfViewGroup)
```

The `children` method returns a `Sequence` of children `View`s in the `ViewGroup` which you can iterate by `forEach` and apply whatever operation applicable to `View`s.

Hope it helps!